# Display Math in phaser.js entitiy

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax, phaser-framework

I am currently working on a game which have to display some math problems. I have tried **MathJax** in HTML environment, and have nice experience with it. However, I have no clue on how to make my phaser game display it on a entity, just like fixed with it.

P.S.: It is not possible to simply embed a image of it since there will be chance for users to type in their own math equation.
P.P.S.: They could be something like just embed a `div` into a entitty.

Comment: Your "P.S." indicates you are planning to have some kind of editing which si a very different (and much more complex) problem. You can use MathJax to create an SVG, create an image with the svg text as data-uri and load that image into a canvas element. I don't know phaserjs much but from a quick look it seems to have straight forward APIs for image loading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with MathJax, but it seems to output either HTML or SVG code. The main focus of Phaser.JS is the canvas element, bitmap graphics, sprites etc.

I don't see how you could combine MathJax with Phaser in a useful way, because you can't display HTML or SVG inside a canvas as far as I know.

If you want to create a game using MathJax, I'd suggest combining it with jQuery or Angular for the animations and transitions.

Answer (score 0):

If your game doesn't use any physics properties you should just use HTML elements and interact with them with something like Jquery.